# React components as instances like in OO programming

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I created React component using React.creatClass ()

```
module.exports = React.createClass({ // input-field-units.jsx is the file name
    displayName: 'input-field-units',
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div >
                <form className="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div className="implement-width-select">
                        <input id={inputid} type="number" className="form-control" onChange={this.onChangeTest}></input>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <select id="implement-width-unit" className="form-control" defaultValue="m" onChange={this.onChangeTest} >
                                <option value="m" >m</option>
                                <option value="mm">mm</option>
                                <option value="ft">ft</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        inputid = this.props.inputid;
        console.log("component: " + inputid);
    },
    onChangeTest: function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _unit = document.getElementById("implement-width-unit").value;
        var _widthValue = document.getElementById(inputid).value;
//processing of code here..
});
```

I intend to call this component like objects in C# where values of properties are not shared if this is called several times.  here inputid is set from this.props.inputid in componentWillMount()

Im using this component on several places in my application (distributed code is in a single file). In my .jsx file I am doing this

```
var InputFieldUnitsComponent = require('../Components/input-field-units.jsx');
var ImplementWidthID = "Implement-Width-ID", againWidthID = "again-width-id";

module.exports = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'PathPlannerSidebarHeader',
    render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                <h2 className="sidebar-header-subtitle">Implement Width</h2>
                <InputFieldUnitsComponent
                   inputid= {ImplementWidthID} // 1st call
                />
                <h2 className="sidebar-header-subtitle">again Width</h2>
                <InputFieldUnitsComponent
                   inputid= {againWidthID} 
                />
                </div>
        );
        //....
        })
```

so that everytime I have a new this.props.inputid to set id of 
but the problem is this.props.inputid maintains same value change and hold the last value. eg in this case inputid will have "again-width-id" even when I want to use for 1st time I called the component.

In short I like OO behavior where the properties of objects are not shared with each other.

Please ask if this doesn't make sense I will explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially made `inputid` a global variable by not declaring it with `var` (or `const` or `let`).

You could say `this.inputid` in `componentDidMount`, but that doesn't make a lot of sense: why have the same value as both `this.inputid` and `this.props.inputid`

It's simpler to just use `this.props.inputid` consistently. If you want to simplify `render()`, define it as a local variable in there.

I suggest to install [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) and enable it in your editor to find this kind of errors.

---

You also need to update the function `onChangeTest`. It's not correct to try something like:

```
 onChangeTest: function() {
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var _widthValue = document.getElementById(this.inputid).value;
   });
 }
```

`onChangeTest` is a method of your react class, but the anonymous function that you're passing to `ready()` isn't, and it can't refer to your react component via `this`... unless you bind it!

```
 onChangeTest: function() {
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var _widthValue = document.getElementById(this.inputid).value;
   }.bind(this));
 }
```

or with the ES6 syntax:

```
 onChangeTest: function() {
   $(document).ready(() => {
     var _widthValue = document.getElementById(this.inputid).value;
   });
 }
```

Obligatory reading: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I can't use onChangeTest: function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _unit = document.getElementById("implement-width-unit").value;
        var _widthValue = document.getElementById(this.props.inputid).value;

because it gives undefined for this.props.inputid

Comment: @TalalHussain that's another story, I've expanded the answer

Comment: Thanks.. .bind(this); solved my problem. Also, for others, please also use this.props.inputid .. directly .. Again, I'm new to JS and React so was my mistake. But thanks @kos